# How can I modify and remove special characters in keys of Python2 dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, unicode, key

I am trying to get rid of special characters in Python dictionary keys and add the `year` of the key to its corresponding `value` if the year exist:

```
{'New Year Day 2019\\xa0': 'Tuesday, January 1', 'Good Friday': 'Friday, March 30', 'New Year Day 2018\\xa0': 'Monday, January 1'}
```

The key and values are all string. I want this to look like the following:

```
{'New Year Day': 'Tuesday, January 1, 2019', 'Good Friday': 'Friday, March 30', 'New Year Day': 'Monday, January 1, 2018'}
```

I have tried to remove `\xa0` but was unsuccessful:

```
    for key in data:
        key.replace('\xa0', '')
        print key
```

I think I will need to use the `(re.search(r'[12]\d{3}', key)).group[0]` regex for getting the year. But how will I remove it from the keys?

Comment: What comprises the set of "special characters"? What was unsuccessful about your attempt to replace `'\xa0'`.

Comment: In the [docs for `str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace), note that a _copy_ of the string is _returned_--the string isn't modified in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the special character "\xa0" you are trying to remove from the keys, try this:

```
data = {'New Year Day 2019\\xa0': 'Tuesday, January 1', 'Good Friday': 'Friday, March 30', 'New Year Day 2018\\xa0': 'Monday, January 1'}
for i in data:
    if "\\xa0" in i:
        data[i.replace("\\xa0", "")] = data.pop(i)
print data
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

you can rename the `value` of keys, add new `key` add remove the old ones:

```
dic = {'New Year Day 2019\\xa0': 'Tuesday, January 1', 'Good Friday': 'Friday, March 30', 'New Year Day 2018\\xa0': 'Monday, January 1'}

for key in dic:
    if key != key.replace('\\xa0', ''):
        dic[key.replace('\\xa0', '')] = dic[key]
        del dic[key]

print(dic)
```

the result will be:

```
{'Good Friday': 'Friday, March 30', 'New Year Day 2019': 'Tuesday, January 1', 'New Year Day 2018': 'Monday, January 1'}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the elegant solution.